# Best way to compare income of two groups of people over time

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, panel-data, intervention-analysis

I am planning a research study where, among other things, I want to understand how an intervention changes income in two groups. I plan to collect income data from each individual at three time points.

What would be the best test to run to validate my intervention (i.e.: To be able to say that, in the event of increase in income in the treatment group, the increase is statistically significant?)

My thought at this point is:

1. Compare incomes of both groups at each time point
2. Where there are differences, run a regression (`income ~ group) on income at that time point.

OR

1. Look at income change of both groups (graphically using line charts)
2. Understand differences in income at each time point.
3. Fixed effects panel regression on the data.

What would be the best way to go about the analysis (exploration/descriptives and analysis)?

Comment: When does the intervention take place in relation to the three time points? Is it a [case-control study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case%E2%80%93control_study) or a [randomized control trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_controlled_trial)? Do you expect changes in [both the intervened and nonintervened groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences)?

Comment: Right now the time points are planned to be 6 months apart. The intervention is availing an on-going service-- I have a group who are already signed up for the service and I want to compare their income progression with those who have not signed up. It is a case-control study